# Embed button for post screen

Tags: posts, media, embed

i would really appreciate it if someone could help me change the "add media" button on the post screen, and make it rather go straight to "insert from url" so that my users embed a link without inserting a media file into the post.

(i apologize for the bad explanation)

any help will be appreciated, thank you.

Comment: The community, usually, comes to help when you've some attemts to get your idea done. Please share some code/approaches you've tried.

Comment: ive been searching the internet for solutions for a few days and could not find anything, thats when i came here.let me rather provide a different question, is it possible to add a button that opens a window to allow them to embed a link?